# Save X,Y and Z data in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know what is the best way to save X and Y and Z points in a database, However the amount of data might be huge.
I tried to save them as a text and the convert to numbers, It worked but i want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: Put them in 3 columns in the table, either `INT` or `FLOAT` depending on your needs.

Comment: Why would you consider anything else?

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail? Where is the data coming from? How do you get it in your PHP script to begin with?

Comment: the data is coming from an excel file a get them with a php script and i save them in database but the number of rows is huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to store them in a numeric datatype, so you don't have to format and parse them when saving and retrieving.

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (
    X INT,
    Y INT,
    Z INT,
    -- other columns here
);
```

If you need fractional coordinates, change `INT` to `FLOAT`.

Comment: i already thought about that but the number of rows is huge so i would have a lot of rows in the table that would make a problem especially when getting the data it will make the app slow

Comment: You'll have the same number of rows if you store them as strings.

Comment: Databases are designed to store lots of rows, don't be scared of it.

Comment: by huge i mean 1000 rows in a single file at least would that be okay ??

Comment: i magine by time how many rows i would have in the database

Comment: 1000 rows is trivial. Databases are routinely used to hold many thousands, even millions of rows.

Comment: okay thank you so much